# Lock request timeout Exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dotnet exe app in a server which runs in sql server. during the factory production time my application were unable to connect to db for 1 to 2 minutes and then it gains connectivity at this unresponsive time when i accessed sql server management studio, i got the below error:

[image: ErrorScreenshot]

Comment: Go to run>services.msc, and restaart SQL Server service.

Comment: You know computers have a `Print Screen` key, and Windows has a tool called "Snipping Tool", right? You don't need to use a phone/camera to take a picture of your screen.

Comment: Prabhat G ..actually i cant do it regularly because it happens twice or thrice a day

Comment: You have to assess various factors such as Ram, memory and CPU utilization during peak hours. What is memory allocated for SQL server?, increase that memory and you wouldn't have issues . But this would be a temporary fix, also need to analyse how much RAM is used by `.net` application within server and any other processes consuming most `cpu usage`

Comment: To solve this, you need to first understand what's going on in your SQL Server. For example, are there open transactions that end up blocking you. The error means you're trying to obtain a lock, but are not able to do so, because someone else is there.

Comment: I **assume** that error is happening when you try to connect. If so, that (likely) means that either someone/something is locking a (or several) system table in `master` (which it really shouldn't be), or you have a server trigger that occurs on connection, and the table that trigger is trying to access has a lock on it. Either way, this seems to imply there is a flaw in your application/trigger design.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the answer over [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23335/lock-request-time-out-period-exceeded-error-when-trying-to-see-db-hierarchies).
This usually happens when there are too many open transactions that are blocking read access to your database server. You can try restart your server which will usually solve the issue.